# Language word existance in php

Tags: php, wamp, pspell

I used php extension pspell to identify existence of english words, however, some combinations return from the server as true words when infact they are not.

For instance the combination "kt" returns "true", I am not sure why.

Is there a way to "harden" the vocabilary that comes within pspell? and if so, how can I do that?

Will enchant give better results? ( i`m trying to enable to on my wampserver ).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done any form of research online on this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of php 5.3. `Pspell` is no longer supported/bundled. Instead you can use the `enchant` which is bundled by default in 5.3.

Kt is a legal word, just google it. One option would be to use [pspell_config_ignore](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-config-ignore.php) to ignore very short words.

Comment: Eventually I went with a client dictionary based config, much faster.